# How can I tell when a user is logged in?

Tags: functions, users

I have a simple problem: when the user is logged in a podcast player is shown; otherwise it isn't.

How can I verify when the user is logged in?

Answer (score 3):

There is really fitting function called [`is_user_logged_in()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in).