# Conditions for Users and Visitors

Tags: functions, conditional-content

I've got a domain that is under development and have created a plugin that uses `wp_die()` in a function I wrote. It must be checked against user auth which is conflicting with my plugin because `init` checks the user auth before `wp_head`.

```
function coming_soon(){

    wp_die();

}

echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi">';

}

add_action('wp_head', 'coming_soon', 10);
```

**Updated**

It should check if a user is logged in and if not `wp_die` and `echo` the redirect. As is, this does exactly what it is intended, I just need it to check a condition if is logged in else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I tell when a user is logged in?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27946/how-to-know-when-an-user-is-loged-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

You just need to add a custom hook to anything after `parse_request` and attach your *coming soon* content or *redirect* to that hook  as you see fit. Hooking earlier then `parse_request` will cause WP to not be able to redirect */wp-admin/* to *wp-login.php*. 
You could also use [php redirect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) if that is the behaviour you are looking for. Like so

```
function coming_soon(){

  if( ! is_user_logged_in() && $GLOBALS['pagenow'] !== 'wp-login.php' )
    do_action( 'coming_soon_content' );

 }
 add_action('parse_request', 'coming_soon', 5);


add_action( 'coming_soon_content', 'my_coming_soon_page' );
function my_coming_soon_page(){

  echo '<h2>Coming soon!</h2>'; // your coming soon content or
  echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi">'; // if using meta refresh
  header('Location: http://www.example.com/'); // if using php header()
  exit; // if using header()

  wp_die(); // this is where die should be

}
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Just check if user is logged with [`is_user_logged_in()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/). Additionally, I would hook early (init) and check that we are not on the wp-login.php page so a user can still login! This will make sure nothing runs on your site if someone is not logged in. using `wp_head` as a hook, you still have a lot of things that are loaded before the check is made.

```
function coming_soon(){

  if( ! is_user_logged_in() && $GLOBALS['pagenow'] !== 'wp-login.php' )
    wp_die();

}
add_action('init', 'coming_soon', 5);
```

Comment: I see what you did there. But it hooks too early. I'm using the `wp_die()` as an action in `wp_head`.

Comment: This still works, but you can definitely hook in wp_head if that is what you need :)

Comment: It does. However in my scenario I'm outputting the function in `wp_head` which is loaded after the user has been auth whereas I need to check the user after `wp_die` in order to get the coming soon page to show.

Comment: oh! well that's a total different scenario! I thought you _only_ wanted to die() requests for non logged in users!  Maybe try updating your question with that bit of info... I'll update my answer to reflect this new information

Comment: I see you updated your question, now just to make sure I understand what you are trying to achieve.  If a user is not logged in, he gets a message/HTML that tells him something along the lines "website coming soon" right? do you have any other specification for that coming soon page?

Comment: I'll update the question.

Comment: Ok check it out now.

Comment: ok updated the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44025/discussion-between-jarmerson-and-bynicolas).